# Is it necessary to use something else than HTML to make static website with very small dynamic content

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am C/C++ developer and know basic HTML, we are planning to make website which have paypal (or maybe other vendor) integration and everything else is static content. Can I not make this website solely in HTML, many people suggesting me that, it is very essential to use server side language like ASP.Net or PHP etc for paypal integration.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do paypal integration with a bit of JavaScript on the client side. No need for a server-side language. In fact you can even do basic paypal integration with no JavaScript, just set up a form that posts to paypal.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan if you say so ;)

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Thanks for your nice words, I am new to web design and development, that is why I am posting questions here. If you know answer, post it, why unnecessary crap.

Comment: Unfortunately [he's wrong](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics).

Comment: @GGG That is not "integration". Pranit's friends ("many people") are correct: "it is very essential to use server side language like ASP.Net or PHP etc for paypal integration.".

Comment: Oh really? Because on their page about integrating paypal with your web site, it's one of the options they mention. Sure you can use their  API from a server side language, but it's certainly not necessary for integrating paypal with your site and taking payments. I am assuming "essential" means "necessary" here.

Comment: @GGG PayPal does have a wide array of initiating a payment methods. Although many use a button on the website, those which needs "integration" have server side requirements (like using a certificate to encrypt the request (which will contain IPN information too) into the button) while others (which are not "integration") are fire and forget pregenerated URLs (by PayPal).

Comment: @PranitPKothari His insights is what Google has done for him, and it could have done for you.

Comment: Ok.. I think we are using different definitions of "integration." I'm going by paypal's defintion, which seems to include the form post thing. And no, the insights are from experience. When customers want to "integrate paypal," often they are perfectly happy with a form post amounting to ten minutes of work.

Comment: I think that is the kind of intergration Pranit P Kothari meant - the button. You dont NEED anything else. You can do all sorts of stuff, but you dont need to.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Oh I forgot, only you have real insights on stackoverflow.

Comment: @PranitPKothari You need to put more effort into your question. What are your application requirements?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: OK, I will edit it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends largely on what you want to do. It is possible to send request and users to PayPal without any server side code by using the PayPal forms/buttons. However in most cases this situation is not ideal as it means you have to manage what people have paid for manually by looking at the PayPal account.

Most websites (e-commerce) will have server side code which links to databases. This will handle transactions, purchase identifiers, user accounts (if applicable) and a variety of other things. You will also want server side code if you want to make use of the Instant Payment Notification system which is handy for knowing when a transaction has been successful/failed and so on.

If you want users to be able to buy something and then download it from your website you will want the later option. Unless you plan on setting up access accounts manually on a user-by-user basis.

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer, I am bound to learn PHP.

Comment: No worries, if you already know C/C++ it shouldn't be too bad, the logic is roughly the same. It's just syntax differences and the fact PHP is loosely typed due to it's scripting nature.

Comment: OK, I will start learning PHP.